# C++ - Can I receive events from other Windows Services?

Tags: c++, windows, service

I use function

```
g_StatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(L"AdobeARMservice", HandlerEx, NULL);
```

and tell the name of another service (not the service I've created).

I want to receive service events like `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want. Please clarify. Of course you can't register a handler for a service you did not create. What are you really trying to achieve? This sounds like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Thanks! I want to get service events from services i didn'create, not quering them in loop (maybe by getting events in callback function, or something else).

Comment: windows maintain only one (single) entry for registered handler. call `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` probably will be "succeeded" if you make from it the same process, where *AdobeARMservice* running (so must be `SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS` service type), but with this call you overwrite original *AdobeARMservice* handler. as result when some control will be send to this service - will be called your new handler , but not original.

Comment: but you also can not report new service status - you have not original `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE`, and for your new handle, returned by `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` - `SetServiceStatus` report status for **another** record in services.exe, not for which was control sent.as result you break *AdobeARMservice* service and your hook service also will be not worked as well. so only break will be

Comment: @ИгорьБондаренко: again, what EXACTLY are you trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to intercept SCM events that are meant for other services than your own? What is your end goal? What you describe is highly irregular.

Comment: I have my own service "My_Service". I want to receive event , when another service ("spooler") stopped or crushed. My service can't work without "spooler" service. Thanks!